# Syntax Error while compiling the code

Tags: python, python-3.6

invalid syntax

there is an invalid syntax error in the line for comma before e:

except (socket.error, socket.gaierror), e:

how to remove it[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9daCS.jpg)

Comment: Please post code and error messages here on SO,  not pictures of it.

Comment: You should post your code here. An image is good but posting your code is even better.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links on that page.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `,` (highlighted) with `as` instead.

The `,` specifies multiple values you have only used one here.  The `as` statement (as it suggests) gives the value `socket.error, socket.gaierror` as the single value `e`, which means both can be referenced as the single value `e`